# added property to an object not taken into account in IQueryable<object>

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity-Framework (Sql Server 2012, ADO .Net Entity Data Model, VS2012 express web).

I'v added a new property to generated partial class.

When I query this object, `IQueryable<object>` does not have this new property.

Why is this newly added property not taken into account?

How could I have it?

Sorry, here is the code :

The generated Entity-Framework class :

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//    Ce code a été généré à partir d'un modèle.
//
//    Des modifications manuelles apportées à ce fichier peuvent conduire à un comportement inattendu de votre application.
//    Les modifications manuelles apportées à ce fichier sont remplacées si le code est régénéré.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace SpaCovoiturage2.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Users
    {
        public Users()
        {
            this.PersonalizationPerUser = new HashSet<PersonalizationPerUser>();
            this.Trajet = new HashSet<Trajet>();
            this.Voiture = new HashSet<Voiture>();
            this.WebpagesOAuthMembership = new HashSet<WebpagesOAuthMembership>();
            this.Roles = new HashSet<Roles>();
        }

        public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Somewhere else in the .Net Solution, the added property (in another part of this class) :

```
namespace SpaCovoiturage2.Models
{
    public partial class Users
    {
        public string SerializedPhoto
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

And so, while debugging, I can see here :

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Users> Users()
{
    return _contextProvider.Context.Users;
}
```

The new added property SerializedPhoto doesn't appear.

Any idea ?

PS : It's in a SPA website (any consequence ?)

Comment: Something is wrong somewhere. Post more code. Especially of your query.

Comment: Please post the definition of your new property.

Comment: I add : in the Users getter, the generated select doesn't contain the added property (for the new property isn't a column in Users table), but the result's collection contain the added property. But I can't access it